# Is there an equivalent to HTML5 IntersectionObserver to measure how far is an element from the root?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML5 IntersectionObserver API let you know how much of an element is shown on the screen, see [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/matuzo/IntersectionObserver-Examples/blob/master/threshold.html).

I would like to measure (in pixels or %) how far is an element from the viewport top. I know it's possible to do with janky js scroll events but I would like to do it in HTML5.

Comment: Do you mean start of the page top or viewport top?

Comment: I meant the viewport top, edited.